# std::unordered_map allocation, insert and deallocation time

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have approximately 4million values in a file which i want to store in a container for performing computations.

The key of each value consists of 2 unsigned integers 
The value is a struct containing 4 double numbers.

The values will not change after loaded.

```
typedef pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> aa;
struct MyRecord { double a1; double a2; double a3; double a4; };

class MyRecordHash{
public:
    size_t operator()(const aa &k) const{   return k.first * 10000 + k.second;      }
};

struct MyRecordEquals : binary_function<const aa&, aa&, bool> {
  result_type operator()( nm lhs, nm rhs ) const
  {
    return (lhs.first == rhs.first) && (lhs.second == rhs.second);
  }
};     

std::unordered_map<aa,MyRecord,MyRecordHash,MyRecordEquals> MyRecords;
```

I use MyRecords.reserve(number_of_records) prior to inserting the records.

Problem A: Although i call reserve before i start inserting the data, the memory allocated is not sufficient and keeps reallocating more and more memory as it inserts the data. Shouldn't it allocate the required memory with reserve? For example for 4m records it allocates with reserve 38.9Mb and then after the inserts an additional 256.5Mb.

Problem B: The insert process is rather slow. I checked the load factor, and it never increases more than 0.5. Are there any suggestions for anything else to check? I use MyRecords.insert for insertion.

Problem C: After i complete my calculations i call MyRecords.clear() . Instead of deleting the contents "instantly" it starts removing record by record (approx 3Mb/second). If i don't call clear() i get the same behavior. Is this normal? I checked all previous stackoverflow questions and the only suggestion i found was that it might be related to debugging. I used the -O3 option but it didn't change anything.

I am using the MinGW-64 compiler 4.9.1 version.

Thank you all for reading this and for your suggestions.

**EDIT After Comments and Solutions proposed:**

-It seems that there is no way to release or preallocate the memory of the STL for unordered_maps when using other than standard types for the the key and the data contained.
-The Reserve method, reserves memory only for the hashes.
-Using a vector<> with indexes computed from the key of the values worked very well. Just preallocate the vector, then using myvector.at() = value, set the values. The default destructor releases the vector almost instantly (with 4m values takes 2-3secs rather than 5minutes with the unordered_map).
-Memory usage with the vector is less since no key is stored
-Random access to the vector seems a little slower though, haven't profiled the code yet.

Thank you all again for the help.

Comment: It's normal for any container to delete objects one-by-one, it has to call the destructor for each anyway.

Comment: The user must wait 4-5 minutes for the deletion! Isn't there another way to do this?

Comment: No i am not, why you say this?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by "wait 4-5 minutes for the deletion". I withdraw my comment.

Comment: if you want you can try boost flat_map, it will use less memory but will be slower.

Comment: sidenote: I am not sure it is guaranteed by language that your hashing is correct, since FP operations can have small errors, so you may want to check that out or ask another question wrt to this.

Comment: anyway i think your hashing may be bad for some inputs, please see this: http://ideone.com/qGYDit

Comment: In my case, the key values go like:
uint,uint
1,1 = 10001 (hash value)
2,0 = 20000
2,1 = 20001
2,2 = 20002
3,0 = 30000
3,1 = 30001
... 
So there is no chance the hash will not provide a unique value, if that's what you mean

Comment: `unordered_map` is node-based. Each insertion is a separate allocation, and deallocating 4 million chunks of memory can get expensive quite fast. `boost::flat_map` is a good choice. Using a custom allocator can also alleviate the problem.

Comment: I suppose I'll ask the obvious question, are you sure you need an associative container? If you have entries covering almost all key combinations then maybe a vector will do, if you are fine with wasting a bit of space for unused entries.

Comment: It is possible to use a vector but then i will have to sort the data as they are not necessarily given sorted.

Comment: @Nonen What do you mean by "given sorted"? Do you mean the keys/value pairs are not encountered in order? If you are just mapping key/value pairs than the order you encounter those pairs is irrelevant since the keys should be unique.

Comment: Yes they are not encountered in order. As i understand it, if i use a vector, either i will have to sort the vector items or use find to get each time the value. Wouldn't this be slower?

Comment: @Nonen No you don't have to search the vector since each entry will be indexed by key. So lookup will be `vector[ key ]`.

Comment: Can you provide some code on this, cause the [key] in a vector will actually be the distance from it's first element. Unless i am missing something.

Comment: It depends on whether it is possible to transform your current key into an zero-based index in a way that permits efficient access (and memory usage).

Comment: Ok got your point. I think this is a good solution to overcome this. Since i am new to stackoverflow i don't know if you should type it below and i mark it as answer although it doesn't answer directly my first questions. Probably the answer is "no you can't but you can do..."

Comment: @Nonen I've added an answer based on these comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from comments...

---

I suppose I'll ask the question (to look at things in a different light), are you sure you need an associative container?

If you have entries covering almost all key combinations then maybe a vector will do, if you are fine with wasting a bit of space for unused entries. So treat your keys as indices into your vector. This will give you constant time lookup and allow you to allocate all the required memory up front, avoiding the cost of multiple allocations.

The value of this approach will depend on the distribution of keys in the key space and just how easily they can be mapped to a zero-based array index.

If you do try this approach I would be quite interested to see how this performs relative to what you're currently doing.

Answer (score 3):

All `unordered_map::reserve` does is increasing the number of buckets so that you won't exceed the max load factor when inserting the specified number of elements. That's not going to help you.

`unordered_map` is a node-based container; as a result, every insertion is a separate allocation. Your data structure's destructors are trivial, but deallocating 4 million chunks of memory is quite expensive.

You can

- Use a custom allocator that handles your allocation pattern efficiently,
- or switch to a different data structure. `boost::flat_map` is a good choice (and the slightly increased time complexity may well be offset by performance gains from better data locality).

Comment: `flat_map` is a good idea if he already has the elements sorted according to the hash value. Otherwise inserting into the array will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

`reserve` probably allocates space only for the hash structure (vector of pointers to data for example) rather than the data itself.

Take your example of inserting 4M records. Each record is 4 doubles or 4*8 bytes. 4M records mean 4*8*4=128Mbytes of data. So obviously, the 38.9Mbyte reserve() allocation is not enough.

Comment: You are right on this, but then isn't there a way to reserve memory space for the data and not for the hashes?

Comment: You might be able to reduce the setup time using c++11's `emplace` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/emplace/). When reading from the file immediately create the object that will be part of the map.

Comment: Emplace didn't make any improvement, just tried it. Thanks for the suggestion.